# Weak form of Poisson-equation in 3D-cylindrical space (heat conduction)

Tags: weak-derivatives, poissons-equation, cylindrical-coordinates

I'm currently trying to code a FEM-program (finite element method) to solve a heat conduction problem including a few tricky things like phase change and a chemical reaction.

In a FEM-book [REDDY - An introduction to nonlinear finite element analysis]  I've found a formulation for a problem in cylindrical space (dependent on $r,z$) that is applicable to the problem I'm trying to solve. However I can't fully follow the derivation that has a minor difference to my derivation. I'll try to document my derivation as comprehensive as possible. I don't know whether such detail is necessary - you might just have to take a look at the very last couple of passages I wrote to give me an answer.

I first do the formulation of eq. 1 in cylindrical coordinates:

The governing equation is $$-\operatorname{div}(a\cdot \operatorname{grad}u)=-\nabla\cdot(a\cdot\nabla u)=f \qquad (\text{eq. }1)$$

with: $$a=\begin{bmatrix}a_{rr}&0&0\\0&a_{\phi\phi}&0\\0&0&a_{zz}\end{bmatrix}.$$

To my knowledge in cylindrical coordinates $(r,\phi,z)$ the following statements are valid:

\begin{align*}\operatorname{div}u&=\cfrac{1}{r}\cfrac{\partial}{\partial r}(r\cdot u)+\cfrac{1}{r}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial \phi}+ \cfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}\\
\operatorname{grad} u&=\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\cfrac{1}{r}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial \phi}+\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}.
\end{align*}

With those statements eq. 1 becomes

$$
-\cfrac{1}{r} \cfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(a_{rr}r\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)
-\cfrac{1}{r^2}\cfrac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\left(a_{\phi \phi}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial \phi}\right)
-\cfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(a_{33}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial z} \right)
-f=0\qquad (\text{eq. }1a)
$$

Considering that by the definition of the problem $u$ is independent of $\phi$, which means $\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial \phi}=0,$ we get:

$$
-\cfrac{1}{r} \cfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(a_{rr}r\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)
-\cfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(a_{zz}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial z} \right)
-f(r,z)=0\qquad (\text{eq. }1b)
$$

So far, so good, this is the same equation the book gives me.

The next step in FEM is to discretize the region and develop a weak form of the equation on an element level.

To get the "weak form" of eq. 1b $u$ is approximated (discretization of the domain):

$$u \cong \sum_{j=0}^n u_j\varphi_j.$$

$u_j$ symbolizes the value of $u$ at node $j,$ $\varphi_j$ is the approximation function for node $j$ ($\varphi_j=1$ at node $j,$ and $\varphi_j=0$ at every other node). With this approximation, eq. 1b cannot be exactly zero any more. I'll call eq. 1c "Error" $E(r,z)$ for the moment. In FEM this error gets multiplied with a weight function $w$  and integrated over the domain $\Omega$. This weighted residue statement is equal to zero.

$$\int_\Omega (E(r,z)\cdot w)\, dr\, dz\, d\phi=0, \quad\text{or}$$

$$
\int_\Omega \left(-\cfrac{1}{r} \cfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(a_{rr}r\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)
-\cfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(a_{zz}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial z} \right)
-f(r,z)\right)\cdot w\space dr\space d\phi \space dz
=0. $$

If we substitute:

$\biggl(a_{rr}r\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}\biggr)=F_1$ and $\biggl(a_{zz}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}\biggr)=F_2$ we get:

$$
\int_\Omega \biggl(-\cfrac{1}{r} \cfrac{\partial}{\partial r}F_1
-\cfrac{\partial}{\partial z}F_2
-f(r,z)\biggr)\cdot w\space dr\space d\phi \space dz$$

$$=\int_\Omega \biggl(-\cfrac{1}{r} \cfrac{\partial F_1}{\partial r}w
-\cfrac{\partial F_2}{\partial z}w
-f(r,z)w\biggr)\space dr\space d\phi \space dz $$

With:

$$\cfrac{\partial}{\partial r}(wF)=\cfrac{\partial w}{\partial r}F+\cfrac{\partial F}{\partial r}w 
\space \rightarrow \space 
\cfrac{\partial F}{\partial r}w=\cfrac{\partial}{\partial r}(wF)-\cfrac{\partial w}{\partial r}F$$

we can replace:

$$\int_\Omega \left(-\cfrac{1}{r} \left(\cfrac{\partial}{\partial r}(wF_1)-\cfrac{\partial w}{\partial r}F_1\right)
-\left(\cfrac{\partial}{\partial z}(wF_2)-\cfrac{\partial w}{\partial z}F_2\right)
-f(r,z)w\right)\, dr\, d\phi \, dz. $$

Further, due to the divergence theorem the following expression can be rewritten:

$$\int_\Omega\cfrac{\partial}{\partial r}(wF)dV=\oint_\Gamma(wF)n_r\,ds$$

and we get:

$$\int_\Omega \left(\cfrac{1}{r} \cfrac{\partial w}{\partial r}F_1+\cfrac{\partial w}{\partial z}F_2-f(r,z)w\right)\, dr\, d\phi \, dz-\oint_\Gamma\left(\cfrac{1}{r}wF_1\right)n_r\,ds-\oint_\Gamma(wF_2)n_z\,ds,$$

with $F_1$ and $F_2$ re-substituted the LHS becomes:

$$\int_\Omega \left(\cfrac{1}{r} \cfrac{\partial w}{\partial r}a_{rr}r\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\cfrac{\partial w}{\partial z}a_{zz}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right)\, dr\, d\phi \, dz
=2\pi\int_\Omega \left(a_{rr}\cfrac{\partial w}{\partial r}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}+a_{zz}\cfrac{\partial w}{\partial z}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right)\, dr\, dz.$$

In the book however it is (with no derivation at all **where does the $r$ come from??**):

$$2\pi\int_\Omega \left(a_{rr}\cfrac{\partial w}{\partial r}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}+a_{zz}\cfrac{\partial w}{\partial r}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right)\cdot r\, dr\, dz.$$

For the RHS I get:

$$2\pi\int_\Omega wf(r,z)\, dr \, dz +\oint_\Gamma\left[\left(\cfrac{1}{r}wa_{rr}r\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)n_r+\left(wa_{zz}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right)n_z\right]\,ds
$$

$$=2\pi\int_\Omega wf(r,z)\, dr \, dz +\oint_\Gamma\left[\left(wa_{rr}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)n_r+\left(wa_{zz}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right)n_z\right]\,ds.
$$

Again the formulation in the book is very similar and but has **an additional $r$ in each integral** - which I can't grasp where it's from:

$$2\pi\int_\Omega wf(r,z)\cdot r\, dr \, dz +\oint_\Gamma\left[\left(wa_{rr}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)n_r+\left(wa_{zz}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right)n_z\right]\cdot r \, ds.
$$

I'm not quite sure whether it is a valid mathematical operation to put an $r$ in every integral - is it? In this case my solution would be equivalent. Is there any particular reason to where this $r$ comes from?

Comment: Shouldn't $$\int_\Omega \left(-\cfrac{1}{r} \left(\cfrac{\partial}{\partial r}(wF)-\cfrac{\partial w}{\partial r}F_1\right)
-\left(\cfrac{\partial}{\partial r}(wF)-\cfrac{\partial w}{\partial r}F_2\right)
-f(r,z)w\right)\, dr\, d\phi \, dz.$$ be $$\int_\Omega \left(-\cfrac{1}{r} \left(\cfrac{\partial}{\partial r}(wF_1)-\cfrac{\partial w}{\partial r}F_1\right)
-\left(\cfrac{\partial}{\partial z}(wF_2)-\cfrac{\partial w}{\partial z}F_2\right)
-f(r,z)w\right)\, dr\, d\phi \, dz?$$

Comment: You quote the gradient theorem in support of the statement $$\cfrac{\partial}{\partial r}(wF)=\oint_\Gamma(wF)n_r\,ds,$$ but this doesn't look anything like the gradient theorem I know. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem. The gradient happens inside the integral, very much in a Fundamental Theorem of Calculus fashion.

Comment: yes, it indeed should be F1 and F2. and it's the divergence theorem not gradient, and it's missing the colume integral - I'll correct it, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer to my question. During the transformation to cylindrical coordinates or rather when you integrate them over an area / volume, you also have to transform $dA \, or \, dV$. I took a screenshot from a (German) textbook, the graphic should be self-explainatory:

[image: graphic from a (German) textbook]

So $dA=r \, d\phi \, dz \, \rightarrow \, dV= r \, dr \, d\phi \, dz$, which explains the additional $r$ in every integral statement that confused me.